# How to run cmd command in background in invoke-command script block

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

At the moment I have

```
invoke-command -comp $hostname -scriptblock { start cmd.exe "/c E:\Path\To\Script\script.bat" }
```

But this does not seem to run the script like I expect. It returns no error message.

Comment: 1. What is the reason of using `Invoke-Command`? 2. `cmd.exe` does not understand single-quoted strings.

Comment: I use invoke command to run the powershell command on a remote computer

Comment: thanks for advice - i've taken away the single quotation marks, but still the same

Comment: It's still not clear what a result you're expecting and what you've get.

Comment: I am looking for a way to leave the script running , forked off in a separate process on the remote server, then the invoke-command script block returns back to the local scirpt, whilst the E:\Path\To\Script\script.bat is running in it's separate cmd.exe process on the remote server.

Comment: Why are you not looking into jobs or workflow for this use case?

Comment: @LostCrotchet In this case [jobs / sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_jobs) will be most suitable.

Answer (score 0):

If the path does not need to escape any characters, you don't need quotes around it.

```
invoke-command -ComputerName $hostname -scriptblock { start cmd.exe "/c E:\Path\To\Script\script.bat" }
```

If you do need to escape, you can escape the double quotes with the backtick:

```
invoke-command -ComputerName $hostname -scriptblock { start cmd.exe "/c `"E:\Path\To\Script\script.bat`"" }
```

Comment: hi thanks for suggestion I've tried removing the single quotation marks and they didn't replacing with anything - unfortunately still doesn't work. I think I found the reason why; start-process doesn't really work with invoke-command beause once the remote session finishes, all processes it created are destroyed too, so my script cannot finish executing. the WMI (or CIM) class "win32_process" I think can be used to achieve what I want. Just finding out how to use it now.